# Android KeyboardView not resizing on rotate

Tags: android

I've got a custom keyboard for my app, and I can't seem to get it to resize when the device rotates.  You can see what I mean here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zAAr.jpg and here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvjYu.jpg

In my activity, I'm trying to force the keyboard to redraw like so:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(mKeyboardView != null)
        mKeyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
}
```

I've also tried to call invalidate(), but to no avail.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Finally found an answer!  I don't know if it's the right one, but it seems to work.  I had to recreate the keyboard on rotate, like so:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    createKeyboard();       
}

private void createKeyboard() {

    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    mKeyboardView = (MyKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new     MyKeyboardActionListener((Activity)this));
}
```

Also, for the record, it wasn't that the view wasn't resizing; it was.  The problem was that the keys weren't resizing.